# How can I get #evaluate to put its results into the page scope?

Tags: velocity, confluence

I cannot get #evaluate to set a variable using any accepted solution I've seen for turning a JSON string into a map using Velocity in Confluence.

I have a JSON string coming from another system that I use to generate dynamic data. During development, I was able to work with the map directly:

```
#set($textMapRaw = [{"ace":"clubs"}])

$textMapRaw.get(0).ace
```

The last line renders as "clubs".

I had expected to use #evaluate to turn the live data into the array of objects. However, it seems that #evaluate is not putting the declared variable back into scope when I do anything with it. Here's the same map coming in as a string:

```
#set($textMapHtml = '[{"ace":"clubs"}]')
#set($evalHtml = '#set($myMapHtml = '+ $textMapHtml +')')
evalHtml = $evalHtml<br/>
#evaluate($evalHtml)

$myMapHtml.get(0).ace
```

The last line renders as "$myMapHtml.get(0).ace".

I know that $myMapHtml is being evaluated because I was getting an evaluate stack-trace when I didn't append `Html` to the end of it to avoid Confluence's auto-escaping shenanigans.

I've tried it with escaping the hash in set using ${hash}set. I've tried single quotes and double quotes. I've tried it with just setting a string via evaluate:

```
#evaluate('#set($dippity = "doo")')
$dippity

#set($hash = '#')
#evaluate("${hash}set($blue = 'moon')")
$blue
```

No matter what I do with any ratified #evaluate code, it is never evaluated into scope in Confluence. I always get a result identical to an undefined variable.

Note: In our environment, I cannot do a workaround in Java and push it into the template. I need to find a pure, in-template solution.

Comment: If I copy & paste your code in my test environment, using Velocity 1.7 or 2.0, it works... Which version of Velocity are you using?

Comment: Are you doing this in Confluence? That's the trick on this. I believe Confluence 6.13 is using Velocity 1.6.4. But it seems to be an issue with Confluence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears you cannot get the variable back into the current scope, I figured out a workaround. Just use evaluate to pass the array/map to a macro.

You still run into scope issues if you try to manipulate variables outside the evaluated code or the macro it calls, but if you're careful you can code around it.

In my case, I moved another bit of code inside the macro to take advantage of the local scope to determine how many items were processed.

```
#macro(processMap $theMap)
  #set($count = 0)
  #foreach($item in $theMap)
    #set($count = $velocityCount)
    <p>This thing is $item.tweedle</p>
  #end
  <p><b>I did that $count times</b></p>
#end

#set($workaroundHtml = '[{"tweedle":"dee"},{"tweedle":"dum"}]')

#set($eval = '#processMap(' + $workaroundHtml + ')')

#evaluate($eval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Velocity 1.6.4 doesn't allow the evaluation context to be modified from within the `#evaluate` directive. So when using this version, it's not possible to create context entries with a dynamic name.

What you can do, though, is store them in a map:

```
#set( $stringMap = '[{"ace":"clubs"}]' )

#set( $myMap = {} )
#set( $eval = '#set($list = ' + $stringMap + ') #set ($myMap.ace = 
$list.get(0).ace)' )
#evaluate( $eval )

$myMap.ace ## prints 'clubs'
```

Comment: Line 2 has an error because you didn't put a throwaway variable for the set/put directive. Adding that and running the code does not achieve the goal of turning the string into an iterable array of maps. the value of HTML is a string.

Comment: @Kevin - edited per your comments. But seeing your answer, obviously you did get it...

Comment: Thanks for saving me from continuing to try putting the variable back into global scope.